# Have Emacs to automatically latex your Rnw file after knitting

Tags: r, emacs, knitr, ess, auctex

I would like to start a LaTeX after knitting an `.Rnw` file. The meta code shoudl be something like:

```
(defun knit ()
  (interactive)
  (setq rproc (ess-get-process ess-current-process-name))
  (setq c "knit('foo.rnw')\n")
  (process-send-string rproc c)
  ;; Wait for ESS to finish 
  (shell-command-to-string   "cd foo/path & pdflatex foo"))
```

The main problem is to have Emacs to wait for the inferior buffer to finish knitting and only after to start latexing. I found a couple of interesting  functions: `(ess-wait-for-process  ...)` and (inferior-ess-mark-as-busy ...)`, which could possibly work, but I am unable to understand how.

Note that `(shell-command-to-string ...`  is only illustrative. The final choice might be:

```
(TeX-command "LaTeX" 'rnw-to-tex-ext -1))
```

`knit2pdf()` might be a different path to go, but I will lose the benefit of AUCTeX.

---

PS: My question is considered "subjective and likely to be closed" by the SE robot!?

Answer (score 1):

I use `texi2pdf` and have R do it after the knit, but that's apparently the equivalent of `knit2pdf`. I wonder though if you could use `system` to call whatever tex command you want from within R, after the `knit` command, similar to how I use `texi2pdf`.

I'm not an emacs expert whatsoever but for what it's worth here's the function I have in my `.emacs` file.

```
; use knitr (was Sweave) script as compile function for Rnw files
(defun ess-swv-SweaveSh ()
  "Use knitr script to knit an Rnw file and create a pdf."
  (interactive)
  (let 
    ((compilation-buffer-name-function (function (lambda(ign)(concat "*" (buffer-file-name) "*")))))
    (compile  (concat "Rscript -e \".n <- '" (buffer-file-name) "'; library(knitr); knit(.n); library(tools); texi2pdf(sub('Rnw$','tex',.n))\"" ))
  )
)
```

Comment: knit2pdf is just knit + texi2pdf and you don't need to worry for the extension just pass the .Rnw

Comment: Neat, thanks! I suppose this isn't as useful to the OP then as they specified that `knit2pdf` wasn't useful to them. As there's no other answers, I'll add another idea...

Comment: I found a possible solution. Have a look please.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to check the `'busy` property of the inferior ESS process. 
The while loop waiting for it to be `nil` blocks command echo. This is why  you see  `(redisplay)`. To avoid stressing your dear one, I set also a refresh delay `(sleep-for .5)`.
Just in case ESS gets stuck the loop exists after 60 seconds. Adjust it, if you have heavy weight code.

Finally I attached latexing to AUCTeX. Therefore you can customise `LaTeX-command-style`  with the help of `TeX-expand-list` documentation.

The function automatically sets the proper name for files to knit and latex, and sets R working dir to  the .Rnw file to be knitted, so you can source other scripts or load data.
So you can run it everywhere with `M-x knit` or perhaps  associate it  with a shortcut. 
The function saves the buffer with last changes before knitting and opens an inferior R buffer if there is none available; otherwise it uses the existing one.

```lisp
(defun knit ()
  "Save the buffer, knit and latex"
  (interactive) ; You will associate this to you favourite key

  (let* (
    ;; Get names & path
        (cur-dir (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name)))
    (rnw-name (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)))
    (tex-name (concat (file-name-base (buffer-file-name)) ".tex"))

    ;; Create knit command
    (cmd (format "require(knitr); setwd('%s'); knit('%s')"  cur-dir rnw-name))

    ;; Time the knitting  
    (start-time (float-time))
    (wait  60)   ; Lifeboat to exit loop if smt wrong
    )

    ;; Save rnw buffer... you are lazy, I know)
    (save-buffer)


    ;; Send string to R at low-level 
    ;;(setq rproc (ess-get-process ess-current-process-name))
    ;;(process-send-string rproc c)

    ;; or Send line with the ESS wrapper 
    (ess-eval-linewise cmd)

    ;; While loop to check when 
    (setq start-time (float-time)
      wait  60) ; Lifeboat to exit loop after x secs 

    ;; Wait for 'busy property nil, nut not more than wait seconds
    (setq rproc (ess-get-process ess-current-process-name))
    (while  (< (- (float-time) start-time) wait)
      (sleep-for .5)
      ;; (accept-process-output rproc .5) ;alt. way for  process-send-string
      (redisplay)
      (if (not (process-get rproc  'busy)) 
      (setq wait 0)
    (message "Knitting... ")))
    (message "Knitting finished, starting latexing")

    ;; Set LaTeX your fav options. See TeX-expand-list for % pars 
    (setq LaTeX-command-style '(("" "%(PDF)%(latex) -file-line-error %S%(PDFout)")))
    ;; TeX-command requires a 'file function (anonymous here) returning the filename.
    ;; TeX-command/TeX-expand-list say 'file has one opt arg: extension.
    ;; Actually they are 2, despite the second seems always passed true.
    (TeX-command "LaTeX"  (lambda (&optional ext dummy) tex-name))))
```

Comment: Great and I wonder why it isn't the marked answer yet. Please do you have any update to this `knit` function since then? How to add this function to the `TeX-command-list`?